# parse utf code in vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript, utf

Is there a way to parse utf codes in vbscript? What I'd like to do is replace all codes like "\u00f1" in a string for its corresponding character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbb2yd2e.aspx) function does that<sup>*</sup>, only it requires that the Unicode characters are encoded in the `%u***xxxx*` format. So, you'll need to replace the `\u***xxxx*` codes with their `**%u***xxxx*` equivalents first. Here's an example:

```
str = "\u0044\u006F \u0063\u0061\u0074\u0073 \u0065\u0061\u0074 \u0062\u0061\u0074\u0073\u003f"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\\(u[a-f\d]{4})"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

str2 = Unescape(re.Replace(str, "%$1"))
MsgBox str2
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that `Unescape` also replaces the `%***xx*` codes in the string with the corresponding ASCII characters. So, if `%***xx*` is a legal substring in your string, you'll have to write your own replacement function. Such a function could do the following:

- search for occurences of the `**\u***xxxx*`-like substrings in your input string,
- extract the character code from each match, and convert it from hexadecimal to decimal form,
- call [`ChrW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf.aspx) to convert the decimal character code to the corresponding Unicode character,
- replace each `**\u***xxxx*` match with the coresponding character.

Comment: What does re.Replace(str, "%$1") do? What's the meaning of "%$1"?

Comment: @Carlos: This code performs a replacement operation on the `str` string using a regular expression (`re`). It replaces all occurences of the `u[a-f\d]{4}` pattern (that is, *uxxxx*) preceded by \ with the same text preceded by %. `$1` in the replacement string is a shorthand for this reused pattern.